# Grab current line in buffer as a string in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can i collect the buffer's current line as a string value in elisp? i can do this,

```
(let (p1 p2 myLine)
 (setq p1 (line-beginning-position) )
  (setq p2 (line-end-position) )
  (setq myLine (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))
)
```

but is there anyway i can do it in one line as,

```
(with-current-buffer get-current-line)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you simply want to do this without `p1` and `p2`, i.e. do it all inline, or are you looking for something special?

Comment: `let` doesn't just declare a variable, it also gives it a value.  So your code creates vars, giving them the value `nil` only to immediately set them to something else.  Better skip the intermediate step and do: `(let* ((p1 (line-beginning-position)) (p2 (line-end-position)) (myLine (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))) ...)`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [`thing-at-point`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html):

```
(thing-at-point 'line t)
```

but note that this also returns any newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Another caveat: When point is at the end of the buffer, this call returns the same string, as if point were at the line aboce.

Comment: You can remove the trailing newline with `string-trim-right`: `(string-trim-right (thing-at-point 'line t))`